# Case Statement not matching "*"

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script. It is menu driven.

For some reason, i use a case statement, and after all my options are printed, i use the * to capture anything else the user may type.  but for some reason, my output is not being done.

Example:

```
while [ 1 ]; do
       if [ $MAIN_MENU -eq 1 ]; then
       printMainMenu
       read option
       case "$option" in
            "1" ) printDiskSpace;;
            "2" ) printFreeMemory;;
            "0" ) exit;;
            "*" ) echo "Input not understood.";;
       esac
       fi
done
```

Now what happens is when I use the menu, if i type 1, 2, or 0 it does the proper thing.  but if i typed 55 for instance, it would just redisplay the menu without echoing "input not understood".

Am i missing something here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found out that I needed to remove the quotes around the asterisk... wow.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: You don't need quotes at all except when handling strings with white spaces.

Comment: @nemo: Or strings like `*`, if you don't want them to be treated as patterns. :-)

Comment: +1 self-answers are good for SO (even if you find it at the same time as someone else ;)

Answer (score 7):

Use `*)` not `"*")` for Bash default cases.

So, in your example:

```
 *) echo "Input not understood.";;
```

Comment: I was entering my answer overlapping with you finding it already.  Glad you got it working.